# How to retrieve certificates information from profile configuration on iOS in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is it possible to retrieve certificates information from profile configuration on iOS in nativescript? 
It is needed to make an authorization in enterprise internal system.

Comment: Are you talking about the build certificate, I don't think you even have access to do that in native iOS.

Comment: Probably I have asked wrong question. There might be some approach to sign request to the server with certificate information. Is there anything like that?

Comment: If you meant secured http / SSL pinning, then you must be looking for [nativescript-https](https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https) plugin.